# How do I search for questions I asked but where I haven't accepted an answer?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, search

So you've asked a bunch of questions and have forgotten about them. How do you find out which questions may have been answered without you having accepted an answer?

Comment: [tag:support] seems to come the closest, but it's not really a support request, since I self-answered.

Comment: How do I use data explorer to work out who the biggest culprits are for asking but not accepting (obviously @slytherincess)?

Comment: @Richard I'd rather see who has the most single answers to questions that haven't been accepted nonetheless. But either should be feasible.

Comment: My guess would be me (by a vast margin)

Comment: Or should this be a feature request, to make it a one click affair?

Comment: Richard I've run that query and it's not @Slytherincess. Not even close.

Comment: Dupe-closing this since I've now posted a definitive proposed-FAQ question about the search facility.

Comment: @randal'thor I've transplanted my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enter [`user:me is:question hasaccepted:no answers:1 closed:no`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aquestion+hasaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1+closed%3Ano) into the search box (or click the link).

This searches for

```
user:me         // posts by you
is:question     // questions
hasaccepted:no  // no answer has been accepted yet
answers:1       // it has at least one answer
closed:no       // not closed
```

And there you go.